# How do you specify webfonts outside each HTML file?

Tags: html, css, webfonts

In my current setup, I have this line in the `<head>` of each of my webpages to load a webfont.

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">`

But this has to be on *every* webpage. What if I want to change fonts across the site? Can I put an analogous line in the CSS file? How can I specify the font(s) for my website in one place instead of in each HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one CSS file for your entire website, you can use the `@import` statement.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab');
```

Comment: Can you specify the favicon globally with an `@import` too?